# Pseudopullback of dimension three

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, 2-categories

What is the name of the appropriate analogue of the pseudopullback for dimension three?

That is to say, a pseudonatural equivalence $fg\simeq hj $ which is universal in the obvious sense...

Thank you in advance;